# Detecting overlapping objects with very noisy background

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, imagefilter

I am currently trying to dectect some reflective and overlapping objects in several images. These images all come with noisy background and the objects I want to detect are overlapping badly.
Here are some examples of the images:
[overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZRl7.png) and [sometimes the background can be bad too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpeoX.jpg)

Besides being able to detect the objects, I also want to count them in the future (so when there's an overlap it needs to know how many objects are overlapping).

What I tried was that I denoise the image first, and tried to apply canny edge.

```
image = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(image,None,10,10,7,21) #denoise twice
image = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(image,None,10,10,7,21)
imageblur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(5,5),0) #blur
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 250)
hist = cv2.calcHist([gray],[0],None,[256],[0,256]) #check pixel histogram
#plt.hist(gray.ravel(),256,[0,256]); plt.show()

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7, 7))
dilated = cv2.dilate(edged,kernel,iterations = 1)
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(dilated, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
imcompare = cv2.hconcat([edged,closed])
imcompare = cv2.resize(imcompare, (0,0), fx=0.7, fy=0.7) 
cv2.imshow('Compare',imcompare)
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

And these are my results:
[without bounding boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mgeJ.png), [with boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WvSc.png)

I'm not an expert in CV and I know what I'm trying right now probably wouldn't get me to desired result but I really hope I could get this project done, so any hints or directions are greatly appreciated! I'm willing to study any material that may help, and I just want to at least have a starting point which I could dive into from.

Btw I also tried looking into different color spaces, pixel histogram, watershed...etc but some challenging parts to me is that my "object" is not an object with uniform color but instead covers a big range of intensity (since it's reflective) and the background can be distracting too. I also thought about using neural network or YOLO or some other ML methods but I don't know which one could be the best (since I also want to seperate the overlapping objects).

Thanks to any response!